# Google Chrome flickers calling jQuery.html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, flicker

In my project I use jQuery.html() to refresh an element on the page. The content is received from the server using AJAX. In FF and IE it is working perfect, but in the Chrome I see that it flickers. I realized that it is not related to AJAX. Problem is that Chrome always gets images from the server even they are not changed. Following example demonstrating it. How to prevent Chrome from reloading images from server?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="XXX">

</p>
<script>
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#XXX").html('This is dynamic content from server with an image <img src="alarms.png">');
    }, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just as a general comment here, if you want to display dynamic content on the page, I wouldn't be changing the HTML content of the page every second and putting in the same content. You'd be much better off catching a content change from an AJAX load on interval, or better yet making use of Websockets or long-polling methods to pull in content changes and update the page if and only if there IS a change. That's a much better approach and will also eliminate the "flicker" of constantly refreshing content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching) on how to optimize caching the content. You could also try preloading the image first [here](http://www.thonky.com/javascript-and-css-guide/javascript-image-preload/).

Comment: It was caching issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `window.onload =` before your setInterval function. It will load the function when the webpage is loaded.

Comment: Or better yet since you're using jQuery already, wrap the whole `setInterval` call in `jQuery(document).ready( function() { ... } )` to do that.